# How to TextFormField in flutter when state changes, using Provider/ChangeNotifier?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have an issue with updating text inside `TextFormField` when using Provider as state management.

I reduced my problem to an abstract one (I removed all the clutter code) and here how it works:

- there is a `someValue` in `AppState`
- the `someValue` can be edited via `Form->TextFormField`
- the `someValue` is to be reflected as a title of the AppBar when typing (`onChange`)
- the `someValue` can be updated from **external source** (in the example it is a button that updates it)
- when `someValue` is updated from **external source**, it MUST be updated in text `Form->TextFormField` as well

The last one is causing me the problem. Consider the following code:

AppState.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class AppState extends ChangeNotifier{
  String someValue = '';

  updateSomeValue(String newValue){
    someValue = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:text_ctrl_issue/app_state.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AppState(), child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<AppState>(context);

// following line of code makes it possible for text to be changed by button
// and reflected in TextFormField
// but it causes nasty side effect, that when typing, cursor always goes to beginning of the line
    _controller.text = provider.someValue;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(provider.someValue),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  provider.updateSomeValue(value);
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    provider.updateSomeValue('foo_bar');
                  },
                  child: Text('change text external source'))
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem:
When I added the line `_controller.text = provider.someValue;` it fixed the issue of updating TextFormField when button is clicked, but it create new issue, that when typing in TextFormField, it is also triggered, cause carret of text field to move to the beginning of the text field.

How to make it work so the text (value) of a TextFormField can be updated externally, without causing `carret` issue when typing?

**EDIT**
The answer of Yeasin Sheikh using `addListener` doesn't quite work (it is hacky) because:

1. it listens to every event (e.g. onFocus or cursor changed)
2. it does not take into account situation that EleveatedButton is in different scope than `_controller` (e.g. is in different widget).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way of doing this by listening `TextEditingController`, while the `TextFormField` is the ruler here.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController()
      ..addListener(() {
        Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false)
            .updateSomeValue(_controller.text);
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(context.watch<AppState>().someValue),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _controller.text = 'foo_bar';
                  },
                  child: Text('change text external source'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you can check [riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/)

Comment: Works like a charm. I am just curious if there other way to fix the issue?

Comment: You can also try with calling onChanged , But others approach seems complicated to me

Comment: What if ElevatedButton does not have access to _controller (e.g. they are in totally different widgets)? How to sync TextFormField via provider only?

Comment: You can pass the controller through constructor or read the provider with listen:false

Comment: Isn't the purpose of common state to avoid passing things from one widget to a other as parms?

Comment: yes, that's why I’ve included  *read the provider with listen:false*

Comment: In both of these examples the controller.text is updated with hardcoded text. Isn't the point of the TextEditingController to get the text that the user typed?

Comment: @ezaspi yes it is, perhaps I've posted this way because OP mentioned using Provider.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class AppState extends ChangeNotifier
{ 
   TextEditingController _controller=TextEditingController();

   TextEditingController get controller=>_controller();

   String someValue = '';

   updateSomeValue(String newValue)
   {
      someValue = newValue;
      notifyListeners();
    }
    }
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:text_ctrl_issue/app_state.dart';

void main() {
runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AppState(), child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(),
);
}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
@override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final provider = Provider.of<AppState>(context);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(provider.someValue),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: Provider.controller,
            onChanged: (v) {
              provider.updateSomeValue(v);
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                provider.updateSomeValue('foo_bar');
              },
              child: Text('change text external source'))
        ])),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Is it good practice to have controller in state?

Comment: Yes Sure to have controller in the state

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering the question, please do include a description of what your code or what it does as well.